# Why did Caesar's Legion become hostile to me?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have been neutral to Caesar's Legion, and have not done anything to make them aggressive towards me. I went to see the enslaved Powder Gangers, but I didn't set them free. The Legion was nice to me.

I didn't see any Legion members until I reached New Vegas and was offered an audience with Caesar himself. I received a coin and was told to go meet him. I fast-traveled back to the location with the slaves and the Legion had turned hostile to me.

After killing them, I continued onwards and met more Legion that weren't hostile, started talking to me about the quest, and who then became hostile.

Anyone have an idea what happened?

Comment: Maybe you were dressed as the NCR or some other faction? That often turns a faction neutral/hostile towards the player.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you perhaps have Boone travelling with you? If Boone is your current active companion, the Legion will always be hostile to you, because Boone will shoot them on sight, and they tend to return the favor.

Comment: Boone was my partner but was at the lucky38. so i can't believe he would shoot them from all the way over there. But i assume the game would make the legion hostile as long as i have the perk as well.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, as long as Boone is your companion (whether or not he's physically with you), the Legion will be hostile to you. You can remedy this by telling him you should go your separate ways, and if you want, you can still send him to the Lucky 38. As you stated, just having his perk is enough to know he's still technically your human companion.

Answer (score 3):

Fallout New Vegas contains quite a few bugs like this. Because it's such a big game they are easily introduced and the steps to trigger them are usually quite opaque.

That said, the Legion does become hostile if you help the NCR so that might be the reason. Your status is set to neutral *once* when you receive the mark of ceasar, but when you continue to help the NCR (e.g. do a quest for them) it reverts back to the old (hostile) state.

If Boone is your companion the legion also becomes hostile, even if you set him to wait somewhere. You have to send him to Novac or the Lucky 38 through dialog to prevent that.

On PC: Make sure you have the latest patch installed. You can also install the "Community Bugfix Compilation Patch" which fixes a lot of known unfixed bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful about what clothes you are wearing. If you have on a rival tribe's outfit you will usually get attacked regardless of your reputation with that group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wearing NCR armor, the legion will attack you on sight. The same applies to the NCR as well, legion armor causes them to attack you, even if you are on good terms with them. Helmets don't seem to have any effect though, just the armors.